# NativeScript How to set a global tint color?

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

Hello I'm trying to set a global tint Color for my Nativescript App. Especially for iOS. I have been trying to set the appearance() without success. Basically I need to have a global tint color that will tint the Back button of a navigationBar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that this solution is working on iOS but should be called from within a Page so that KeyWindow has had the time to be instantiated.

```
const Color = require("tns-core-modules/color").Color
const mainColor = new Color("#ed1c24")
UIApplication.sharedApplication.keyWindow.tintColor = mainColor.ios
```